# AH00136: Server MUST relinquish startup privileges before accepting connections. Please ensure mod_unixd or other system security module is loaded

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew, httpd.conf

Can't start httpd Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.
httpd and apache are installed with `brew`.

in  `/var/log/apache2/error_log` I always see:

```
AH00136: Server MUST relinquish startup privileges before accepting connections.  Please ensure mod_unixd or other system security module is loaded.
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Can somebody help me what is wrong?

Comment: "Please ensure mod_unixd or other system security module is loaded." Have you done what the message tells you?

Comment: what is unclear in the error message I wonder.

Comment: mod_unixd is included, at the end is message: "AH00016: Configuration Failed" , but  apachectl configtest  return "Syntax OK"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the php.ini you have to place or un-comment the line:

```
LoadModule unixd_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_unixd.so
```

This is a required shared object file for Unix-family platforms.
Then restart apache:

```
brew services restart httpd
```